# Creating simple OWL ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I am new to OWL and i don't know how to create the simplest ontology. 
I need to create a simple OWL for a class. The class name is Movie and the movie has name and year.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe you should take a look at the [OWL Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/)...

Comment: You can have a look at my blog. [Here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2017/09/09/a-simple-class/) is a simple example and [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/) you can download a reference to guide you.